# Continuous moving animation React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, animation

I'm trying to move a ball from a set of coordinates to another. I've succeeded in making the ball move. I can also loop the animation but this is not the final result that I'm looking for: When a ball moves, I would like to make some other balls move, even if the first one did not finish its yet animation. Please have a look at the next picture to get an illustration of what I'm looking for:

Current Behaviour:

[image: Current behaviour]

Targeted behavior (please notice that I've just added some marginLeft in order to take the screenshot):

[image]

You may refer to my snack:

```html
<div data-snack-id="@xavier96/moving-ball" data-snack-platform="ios" data-snack-preview="true" data-snack-theme="light" style="overflow:hidden;background:#fafafa;border:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.08);border-radius:4px;height:505px;width:100%"></div>
<script async src="https://snack.expo.io/embed.js"></script>
```

You can also follow this [link](https://snack.expo.io/@xavier96/moving-ball)

You can also take the exemple of Tesla powerwall app animation, it's exactly what I'm trying to achieve: https://youtu.be/koRS2G5o3ek?t=46

Comment: Can't you just use multiple animations/values?

Comment: This would work I knew how much balls I want to move, but I don't, it's a "looping" animation.

Comment: Looping just means it's repeating over. I am not really sure what are you trying to do, but it seems you have 2 options: 1) use mutliple animations/values 2) use a single animated value but introduce an offset using Animation.add() to get animated value for other balls.